# xml parsing of special characters, such as '&' symbol in php

Tags: php, xml-parsing

I am having trouble to parse special characters from an xml file (I can't edit the file) with special characters, such as the '&' symbol in php.

Here is an example xml code snippet that I try to make it work and display in php.

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<node>
<test>Don't  & forget me this weekend!</test>
</node>`

Any help is highly appreciated  :)

Comment: That XML is malformed. You'll have to fix the producer.

Answer (score 3):

To use the `&` special character the code is `&amp;`

Also have a look at : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Answer (score 1):

In that one corner case:

```
str_replace("&", "&amp;", $xml);
```

Would make it parse properly. Unfortunately if you have a great than or less than sign unescaped:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<node>
  <test>Oh my < Goodness </test>
</node>
```

A `str_replace` is not going work. Now you could do regex to test something like `<[a-zA-Z]`, but then there's:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<node>
  <test>Oh my<Goodness </test>
</node>
```

So that will basically kill your chances of using a regex.

I've tried to parse your XML with SimpleXML, DOM, XmlReader, and attempted a number of libxml properties, and nothing worked.

So in short, the odds are against you. Your provider needs to generate proper XML.